# Is it not possible to use the "use" keyword in PHP with an anonymous function in a closure context?

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function, reduce

I'm trying to execute the following PHP code:

```
$path_hierarchy = // function that returns an array

return array_reduce(
    $terms,
    function($val1, $val2) use ($path_hierarchy) {
        return $val1 || in_array($val2, $path_hierarchy);
    }
);
```

...but I'm getting the following PHP error:

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '{'`

So, I switched to the following syntax:

```
$path_hierarchy = // function that returns an array

$callback = function($val1, $val2) use ($path_hierarchy) {
    return $val1 || in_array($val2, $path_hierarchy);
};

return array_reduce(
    $terms,
    $callback
);
```

...and this worked. Am I not able to use the `use` keyword in the context of an anonymous function as an argument to another function?

Comment: Can you copy-and-paste the code that isn't working? It would also help to see exactly which line it is complaining about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `return $val1 || in_array($val2, $path_hierarchy))`

The problem lies here: the second closing parenthesis.

Comment: That was a typo with transferring the code...I didn't do a straight copy paste.

Comment: To be clear, the typo was on the stack overflow question - my actual code does not have this typo.

Comment: It works perfectly fine if I replace the parenthesis with a semicolon. cf. this: https://gist.github.com/1507535: >php -f "bla.php"
>Exit code: 0